# Salesforce login page in other language

Tags: login

Can some help me here , i need Salesforce login page in other language.

I have tried with locale for Chinese but it is not working and for french and some other languages it is working.

example-https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=fr --working

when I use locale for Chinese (Simplified): zh_CN and Chinese (Traditional): zh_TW it is not working

Answer (score 1):

for Chinese you can use `locale=cn`

https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=cn

https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=tw

[image]

Comment: [`https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=tw`](https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=tw) is the other one.